# Assign IPv4 and IPv6 to different network interfaces

Tags: macos, network

I have 2 ISPs.

Both ISPs are DS IPv4/IPv6 and have the same bandwidth.

However, ISP A has better IPv4 routing, while ISP B has better IPv6 routing.

I've assigned ISP A to Wi-Fi and ISP B to Ethernet (on different routers).

Is there a way to force macOS to use Ethernet for IPv6 and Wi-Fi for IPv4?

IPv6 should have priority over IPv4.

Thanks.

Comment: What does "better routing" mean in this context?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: What’s “DS IPv4/IPv6”?   How do you qualify “better” routing of IPv4 versus IPv6?  What does that mean?

Comment: @MarcWilson ISP A reaches its IPv4 destination in 4 hops and 12ms. ISP takes 36 hops and 600ms to reach the same IPv4 destination. The opposite happens for IPv6 destinations, ISP B takes fewer hops and reaches the destination faster than ISP A.

Comment: @Allan DS means dual stack (the ISP provides both IPv4 and IPv6 natively). By better routing, I mean reaching the destination faster and in the fewest possible hops via IPv4 or IPv6.

Comment: @pmcarrion I would not expect that either ISP is going to always be either 4 or 36 hops.  Do you have metrics indicating one or the other is always faster or slower?

Comment: @MarcWilson The metrics (MTR tests) change occasionally for the services I've tested. However, after all the testing I've done for these services, I can say that ISP A works better for IPv4 and ISP B works better for IPv6. Routing policies evolve, there's no way of saying one will *always* be faster than the other.

Answer (score 4):

Turn off IPv6 on the interface on which you only want to use IPv4.

[image]

For the interface on which you only want IPv6, don't assign an IPv4 address to it.  That *may* cause the OS to assign an APIPA address to it, which still wouldn't be routable.

[image]

Comment: Upvoted because this succinctly answers the question being asked.  The major issuw with the OP’s premise is that assuming a DNS server responds with both 6 and 4 addresses, most servers will reply  with both and the Mac will take the path with the highest priority or least latency.  In other words, it will not work the way the OP intends it to work.